MOSFET losses in an inverter
There is a 3 phase inverter design, which has a DC battery supply. The inverter supplies a delta motor, so the I_line = I_phase*sqrt(3) and V_line = V_phase.
I'm trying to calculate the power loss of the inverter before I build it, so I need to calculate the losses of the MOSFETs. I calculated the switching losses as 6 * 20 kHz * E_total, where 6 comes from the fact that I will have 6 MOSFETs, 20 kHz is the switching frequency, E_total is the total energy needed for the switching according to the datasheet.
However I have trouble calculating the conductive losses, because I can't figure out what the RMS current through each MOSFET will be. Is it the RMS line current? Is it the RMS phase current? I also found one info which said RMS line current / sqrt(2)?
Is the currents will even be same for all MOSFETs? So the total conductive loss is 6 * (RMS IMOSFET)2 * Rdson?
Some numbers: RDSon is 75 mΩ, I_phase is 12 A, I_line is 20.785 A. E_total = 420 μJ --> SW_loss = 6 * 20 kHz * 420 μJ = 50.4 W

By "energy needed for the switching" do you mean the gate charge?  That's only one component of the switching loss, the other is due to the dissipation while the FETs transition state (V and I at the same time).

Yes correct, these energy needed for switching is given by the datasheet, as E_on and E_off at a given Vds, Id, rise and fall time, etc. I just used the simple version of it.

Use a simulator. They are free, will eat this job and be more accurate than hand calculations

I created a simulation, unfortunately I couldnt create 12A phase currents, no matter the wiring resistance and inductance or backEMF. However at some lower loads the RMS currents through the mosfets seems to be the line current / sqrt(2).
